# I want to display apple pay button on checkout page magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom-button

I want to display apple pay button on checkout page magento2 how acheived that

Comment: Please override checkout place order file.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, '/home//public_html/certs/ApplePay.crt.pem');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,'/home//public_html/certs/ApplePay.key.pem');